# Need ASCII Playing Cards to Print on One Line

Tags: python, python-3.x, ascii-art

I am trying to get playing cards that are in a players hand to print on one line instead of separate lines like this:

```
        ┌─────────┐┌─────────┐
        │2        ││4        │
        │         ││         │
        │         ││         │
        │    ♥    ││    ♥    │
        │         ││         │
        │         ││         │
        │        2││        4│
        └─────────┘└─────────┘
```

My cards are in a tuple array with the face and the suit.

I am currently working on a Mac using IDLE 3.7.0 since I know my professor is going to be using it to grade my final project. I think any Mac/Linux solution should work but I am open to anything at this point.

This is my code that creates my cards:

```
deck = [(face, suit)  for face in range(2,15) for suit in ['\u2660','\u2665','\u2666','\u2663']]
```

This is my code to print out the faces:

```
def face_print(card):
face_name = card[0]
if face_name == 11:
    face_name = 'J'
elif face_name == 12:
    face_name = 'Q'
elif face_name == 13:
    face_name ='K'
elif face_name == 14:
    face_name = 'A'

return '%s' % (face_name)
```

This is the code that I am trying to get to work:

```
def hero(playable,dealerHand,nonDealerHand):
    indexDealer = 0
    indexNonDealer = 0
    strNonDealerHand = []
    print(dealerHand)
    for index, card in enumerate(nonDealerHand):
        nonDealerCard = """
 ┌─────────┐
 │{}        │
 │         │
 │         │
 │    {}    │
 │         │
 │         │
 │        {}│                         
 └─────────┘""".format(face_print(card),card[1],face_print(card)).split('\n')

        strNonDealerHand.append(nonDealerCard) 

    print('Your hand: ')
    for i in range(9):
        for index,card in enumerate(strNonDealerHand):
            print(strNonDealerHand[index][i], end = ' ')
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be working.

My output has been looking like this:

┌─────────┐ ┌─────────┐ ┌─────────┐ ┌─────────┐ ┌─────────┐                             │2        │                             │3        │                             │5        │                             │9        │                             │Q        │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │    ♦    │                             │    ♠    │                             │    ♥    │                             │    ♠    │                             │    ♣    │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │         │                             │        2│                             │        3│                             │        5│                             │        9│                             │        Q│                             └─────────┘                             └─────────┘                             └─────────┘                             └─────────┘                             └─────────┘

I tried both of the suggested solutions below, and I end up with this kind of an output:

Your hand: 
┌──────┐ ┌──────┐ ┌──────┐ ┌──────┐ ┌──────┐

```
         │2        │ │4       │ │6        │ │9       │ │Q       │

         │         │ │        │ │         │ │         │ │        │

         │         │ │        │ │         │ │        │ │        │

         │    ♥    │ │    ♣    │ │    ♠    │ │    ♥    │ │    ♥    │

         │         │ │         │ │         │ │         │ │         │

         │         │ │         │ │         │ │         │ │         │

         │        2│ │        4│ │        6│ │        9│ │        Q│

         └─────────┘ └─────────┘ └─────────┘ └─────────  └─────────┘
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, but any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: If that's on Windows, make sure your screen buffer size in the properties of the cmd.exe window is big enough to hold a full line, otherwise it will get wrapped. EDIT: Also, did you forget to put a `\n` at the end of each `for i in range(9):`? EDIT2: Ah Michael saw it, too :)

Comment: After the inner `for`-loop at the bottom add a `print()` to go to next line.

Comment: Can you also paste sample function calls. And the `face_print` function definition.

Comment: Hello @Jeronimo!  I tried what you suggested, but I ended up with stretched out cards. Do you have suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Hello @MichaelButscher!  I tried what you suggested, but I ended up with stretched out cards. Do you have suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Could you replace the print at the bottom of your code with `print(repr(strNonDealerHand[index][i]), end = ' ')`. The `repr` should make undesired characters visible (I guess there could be `\r`s on a Mac).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Hi Michael! I ended up figuring it out. You can check out my answer and see if this is pythonic or if I could have done it better. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work (Linux, Python3)

Key is using zip function to print one row from each card at a time.

```
def hero(playable,dealerHand,nonDealerHand):
    strNonDealerHand = []
    for index, card in enumerate(nonDealerHand):
        nonDealerCard = """
 ┌─────────┐
 │{}        │
 │         │
 │         │
 │    {}    │
 │         │
 │         │
 │        {}│
 └─────────┘""".format(card[0], card[1], card[0]).split('\n')
        strNonDealerHand.append(nonDealerCard)

    print('Your hand: ')

    for i in zip(*strNonDealerHand):
        print(" ".join(i))

hero(1, 'a', [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
```

Sample output: (NOTE: It is not printing symbols. I guess your missing function is doing that job)

```
Your hand: 

 ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐  ┌─────────┐
 │1        │  │2        │  │3        │
 │         │  │         │  │         │
 │         │  │         │  │         │
 │    1    │  │    2    │  │    3    │
 │         │  │         │  │         │
 │         │  │         │  │         │
 │        1│  │        2│  │        3│
 └─────────┘  └─────────┘  └─────────┘
```

Comment: Hello @Krishna! I tried what you suggested, but I ended up with stretched out cards. I did try with a carriage return, but the cards printed in one vertical line but correctly. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running in Windows or Linux. Can you put your code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php so that we can work together

Comment: I'm actually running in Mac on IDLE 3.7.0, which probably would be very close to Linux. I'll get my code over there shortly. Do I need a login or anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out and it worked out really well.

Here is my code:

```
deck = [(face, suit)  for face in range(2,15) for suit in ['\u2660','\u2665','\u2666','\u2663']]

def deal(deck):
    strNonDealerHand = []
    random.shuffle(deck)
    for i in range(5):
        dealerHand.append(deck.pop())
        dealerHand.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0))
        nonDealerHand.append(deck.pop())
        nonDealerHand.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(0))

# The idea for this came about from a lot of research to make the cards print as a card and all on one line.
# Some of the inspiration for this code came from here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/82103/ascii-fication-of-playing-cards
   lines = [[] for i in range(9)]

    for index, card in enumerate(nonDealerHand):
        # add the individual card on a line by line basis
        lines[0].append(str(index + 1) +') '+'┌─────────┐ ')
        lines[1].append('   │{}        │ '.format(face_print(card)))  # use two {} one for char, one for space or char
        lines[2].append('   │         │ ')
        lines[3].append('   │         │ ')
        lines[4].append('   │    {}    │ '.format(card[1]))
        lines[5].append('   │         │ ')
        lines[6].append('   │         │ ')
        lines[7].append('   │        {}│ '.format(face_print(card)))
        lines[8].append('   └─────────┘ ')

    result = []
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        result.append(''.join(lines[index]))

    for card in result:
        print(card)

def face_print(card):
    face_name = card[0]
    if face_name == 11:
       face_name = 'J'
    elif face_name == 12:
       face_name = 'Q'
    elif face_name == 13:
       face_name ='K'
   elif face_name == 14:
       face_name = 'A'

    return '%s' % (face_name)

 deal(deck)
```

This ended up displaying my cards perfectly. Not sure if this is pythonic or not, but I am open to additional feedback.

Thanks!